# Why isn't gas flowing to my fireplace after I open the valve?

Tags: fireplace

I don’t have a pilot light just a key that you turn to open a valve to free gas. I haven’t used it in 3 years and I recently tried but after 30 seconds of the gas being on ,nothing happened.Does it take a while for the gas to flow through the line?

Comment: No. I'd look for another valve upstream.

Comment: Agree about looking for another valve.  Code typically requires a shut off valve close to the point of use - the stove, furnace, fireplace, etc.  This is a safety issue so that someone working on an appliance is not surprised if someone else turns on the valve at the other side of the house.